# Get an item from Datagrid.Items collection in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with some items in it and I need to get them to convert to DataRowView but can't seem to find a way to get each item individually out of the collection.
My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataGrid1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var test = DataGrid1.Items[i];
                DataRowView row = (DataRowView)test;
            }
```

I would imagine `DataGrid1.Items[i]` would get me the item itself but only gets `System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection`

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with how I was adding items into the DataGrid. I was adding them from another DataGrid and since I was using

```
DataGrid1.Items.Add(Datagrid.SelectedItems);
```

All the items in the DataGrid where ItemCollections themselfs that's why selecting an Item from that DataGrid would return an ItemCollection.
The DataGrid looks the same no matter if the items added are actual items or item collections.

So changing how I add items to

```
DataGrid1.Items.Add(Datagrid.SelectedItems[0]);
```

Added items themselfs and not collections to the seconds DataGrid and that way they can be accessed with the code I used in the question.

I'll leave this here in case somebody runs into a similar kind of a problem.